# i need help regarding my project of animating a machine

Tags: mechanical-engineering, solid-mechanics, machining

I am designing a **machine consisting of gears , four bar mechanisms and rollers** but I need the reference of a **software** where I can **draw or construct the instruments and components** and **execute the motion of all the components together** for the **machine to operate** , kindly suggest me something .

Comment: caelinux.com includes freecad which is a 3D design tool like SolidWorks. It also includes FEA, CFD and much more. Although, I'm not sure about simulating motion with it. You can read about freecad here freecadweb.org

Comment: Yes, Python macros can be used to create motion of the assemblies within freecad. And yes, freecad is..., free.

Comment: @Jim Clark , thank you , actually i even need to show the **chip formation a nd screw thread formation on the surface of workpiece** , there will also be a lot of  **relative motion between gears and  shafts** ... it will it be very good if you can tell me more about the software , i have 0 idea or knowledge about graphics and software

Comment: @Transistor has provided a great link of what OnShape might provide you. You certanly have a big task ahead of you. Good luck.

Comment: @Jim Clark , ok i will check it out

Comment: Irresistible to comment:    " It's.... ALIIIIIIIIIVE!!!!!!"

Answer (score 1):

[OnShape](https://onshape.com) is a full featured cloud / browser based 3D CAD software that is free to use if you don't mind your work being publicly accessible. It supports animation. The product quality is excellent. (I have no connection with the company.)

[image]

Here's a [sample linkage animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lKYyn_N1-Qc&ab_channel=LaurenShohen) from YouTube.

Comment: thank you it helped me

Comment: I recommend that you unaccept this answer for a day or two to encourage other - possibly better - answers. Then accept the best and upvote any useful ones.